# Show/hide div Javascript while typing into text field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show a div/hide a div when typing into a text field but when i start typing nothing is showing up. If someone could check my code it would be great thank you!

html + javascript:

```
<body>
    <h1>LIVE SEARCH WITH AJAX TEST</h1>
    <div class="search">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="recherche" class="search" onkeypress="showdiv()">
    </div>
    <div class="resultat" id="resultat" id="resultat" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#">Search Result #1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #2</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #3</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #4</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #5</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function showdiv() {
        if (document.getElementById("resultat").style.visibility=="hidden") {}
          document.getElementById("resultat").style.visibility="visible";
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: `display: none` is not the same as `.style.visibility=="hidden"` so the code inside the if is never executed.

Comment: @yuriy636 There is no code inside the `if`. Your point is still valid, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **set the `display` property on key press**, not the `visibility` property, since you hide it via `display: none`:

```js
function showdiv() {
  document.getElementById("resultat").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="recherche" class="search" onkeypress="showdiv()">
</div>
<div class="resultat" id="resultat" id="resultat" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Search Result #1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #3</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #4</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code:

**Javascript:**

```
function showdiv() {
    document.getElementById("resultat").style.display = "block";
};
```

or

**jQuery:**

```
function showdiv() {
    $('#resultat').slideDown();
};
```

**Also it's better to change your code and write it like this:**

HTML:

```
    <h1>LIVE SEARCH WITH AJAX TEST</h1>
    <div class="search">
    <input type="search" name="search" id="recherche" class="search">
    </div>
    <div class="resultat" id="resultat" id="resultat" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#">Search Result #1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #2</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #3</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #4</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Search Result #5</a>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("recherche").addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    document.getElementById("resultat").style.display = "block";
});
```

The condition in your code was useless and you have to change `display` instead of `visibility`.

Comment: The question does not mention that jQuery is used in the project. Adding a dependency to jQuery just for this use case seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display` property to show/hide the div.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('recherche');
var div = document.getElementById('resultat');

// When the user type, we show the results
input.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
 div.style.display = "block";
});
```

```html
<h1>LIVE SEARCH WITH AJAX TEST</h1>
<div class="search">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="recherche" class="search">
</div>
<div class="resultat" id="resultat" id="resultat" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Search Result #1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #3</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #4</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #5</a>
</div>
```

You can catch the `focusout` event to hide the div.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('recherche');
var div = document.getElementById('resultat');

// When the user type, we show the results
input.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  div.style.display = "block";
});

// To hide the div when the cursor isn't in the input
input.addEventListener('focusout', function() {
  div.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<h1>LIVE SEARCH WITH AJAX TEST</h1>
<div class="search">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="recherche" class="search">
</div>
<div class="resultat" id="resultat" id="resultat" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Search Result #1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #2</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #3</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #4</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#">Search Result #5</a>
</div>
```